# Is there a PowerShell equivalent for "netsh int ipv6 show joins"?

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, ipv6

Is there a PowerShell command that yield the same output as

```
netsh int ipv6 show joins
```

Comment: Things to play with not certain though just some quick googling: `Get-NetNeighbor`, `route print`, and then look at some C# to run with PowerShell which is possible but [`UdpClient Class`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0). I was not able to get it worked out, but in case it helps you dig with a little more accuracy those are potential items to test with to see if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle for the hint.

Somewhat of a poor answer, but it may jog a memory and result in a better answer.

Start experimenting with `Get-NetNeighbor | where-Object IPAddress -Match "224"`

Set the PowerShell window width to 2000 so that no data is lost, then do `Get-NetNeighbor | ft *` and examine all the columns that are returned.  Maybe there is something else that is useful.